# array not being read properly

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2D array.  I am iterating all the 8 rows and 10 columns and reading the values using a for loop.  Here is the our array and the output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

empty row board[3][3] = 0 empty row board[3][4] = 1
empty row board[4][3] = 0 empty row board[4][4] = 2
empty row board[5][3] = 0 empty row board[5][4] = 1
empty row board[6][3] = 0 empty row board[6][4] = 2
empty row board[7][3] = 0 empty row board[7][4] = 2
empty row board[8][3] = 0 empty row board[8][4] = 1
empty row board[9][3] = 0 empty row board[9][4] = 2
empty row board[10][3] = 0 empty row board[10][4] = 1
empty row board[11][3] = 0 empty row board[11][4] = 2
empty row board[12][3] = 0 empty row board[12][4] = 1
```

The actual array is surrounded by buffer of zeros (atleast 3 on each side).  When we try to read row =3, it doesn't read the elements but rather reads them as all zeros.  We have printed below the array the elements of row 3 and elements of row+1, which is 4.  It can read all elements from row 4 but nothing from row 3.  WHY? Please Help!!!

@Mat
Posted Code:

We are trying to find if the row is empty or not.

```
int emptyRow(int row){
    int i, counter;
    counter = 0;

    for(i=3; i<=num_col+2; i++) {
        printf ("empty row board[%d][%d] = %d ", i, row, board[i][row]);
        printf ("empty row board[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, row+1, board[i][row+1]);
        if(board[i][row] == 1 || board[i][row] == 2 || board[i][row] == 3)
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;         /* Counter = 0 means its empty*/
}
```

The row being passed is 3, the counter counts the number of elements in the row, num_col is the number of columns.
The functions returns counter = 0 which means row 3 is empty.

We are reading the input from a file and printing it. This code is part of an AI we are working on, so cannot post all of the code since it is complicated. Print board is posted below:

Row 3 is our boundary condition, so we dont care whats above row 3 but we need to read in row 3 properly

```
void print_board(){
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=0;i< 16; i++){
        for(j=0;j<16;j++){
            printf("%d ", board[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Log value at board[0][0]

Comment: @Mat I posted the code, the edited version. Thanks

Comment: @vsg Can you include the code for logging the whole array value?

Comment: Could You post the code where You fill the board array and the part where you print the whole array?

Comment: The problem might be at the point where You set the values of row 3. Could you post that part?

Comment: We are reading from a file and then storing n printing it. It is reading, storing and printing absolutely fine. I posted my print function but input function is a little complex and cannot post it all by itself. Thanks

Comment: The only explanation I can provide is that `board` was modified between the time your printed it out, and the time you do the empty check. What happens between those two things?

Comment: try to print the board right after `emptyRow` ended or before it starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the displayed output is from a call to `print_board()`, and the debugging output shown is from a call to `emptyRow(3)`, then the only explanation that makes sense is that `board` was modified between those two calls. Check your software to make sure that the `board` contains the values you expect it to at each stage leading up to the call to `emptyRow(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines,

```
    printf ("empty row board[%d][%d] = %d ", i, row, board[row][i]);
    printf ("empty row board[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, row+1, board[row+1][i]);
    if(board[row][i] == 1 || board[row][i] == 2 || board[row][i] == 3)
```

This should work as expected. See previous answers re row/col mix up.
This assumes the board array is in fact 16 x 16 in size, and num_col+2 evaluates to 12.

I would use gdb to run the program and then you can use print board[3], print board[4], etc to see what the program sees.

Answer (score -1):

Row and column interchanged up in the code of **printing the first set of whole array as matrix**

Use

```
 void print_board(){
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=0;i< 16; i++){
        for(j=0;j<16;j++){
            printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The rows and columns are correct and are printing fine. Our AI works fine as well except for in row 3 where it shows its empty. Also, I am not down voting your answers.

Comment: @vsg : Are you SURE? try this

Comment: Please explain why could be this better? it prints the same values, but changes the columns to rows and rows to columns.

Comment: Hi @Lithu! Its a board game that we are coding the AI for. The way we are reading the values from the file is column wise(0 to 10) and then from bottom row to top row(8 to 0). That is how the state of the board is being passed. The way we are printing it is fine and the way it should be.